# Obtaining Full Text of ISO27002

Tags: untagged

You would think this information would be easier to come across but I can't really find it. How do somehow obtain the text of ISO27002? I've tried to find it online in various places (including the IEC webstore) but can't find so much as a "contact sales" message. If it's free, great, if it costs, is there a place where I can get the price?

Comment: http://17799.cryptovb.com/ and http://www.27000.org/standards.htm

Comment: Yeah I found both links in my searching, both are unofficial sources and the first one is only selling the "toolkit" versus just the standards document and the second one just looks shady as hell.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. I'm assuming it's because of "Product, service, or learning material recommendations" in which case I'd like the people who voted to close to actually read the FAQ and see that prohibition is on a "which is better x or y" subjective slug match. This question pertains to an international standard used for constructing IT baselines which falls under the "operations" category in the FAQ. Just because it's not a technical question doesn't mean it's not appropriate to place it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text can be downloaded [here](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=50297) from the ISO website.

EDITED by The Cleaner:  The U.S. version can be found here on the ANSI Site: [ISO 27000](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=ISO/IEC%2027000%20Information%20Technology%20Security%20Techniques%20Collection#.UXln3so9lHY)

Comment: Thanks, I probably should have mentioned that I'm in the United States. The linked page only sells in Swiss Francs (of which I have none) but looking at the page again I did find my answer: the ANSI website is the official source for ISO standards in the United States. Since I found the answer by way of the link I'm marking this as the answer.

Comment: For future reference I've updated the answer